# computational error in Jacobi preconditioner with large numerical value

Tags: c++, matrix

recently, I am working on the iterative solver with C++ languge. For getting better iterations, it's necessry to do some preconditioning.But now I meet a serious problem. Without jacobi preconditioner, I can get a good result. After applying this preconditioner, the iterations  can not get convergence!

The problem I think is about multiplications that I did in jacobi preconditioner. In the code `data` is the value of elements in the matrix which I get from MatrixMarket. generally, it is about 10e8 or greater.
I don't know how to solve this problem.

I attach my code about jacobi preconditioner below

**densematrixvector_imp.h**

```
//Jacobi Preconditioner
template <class M, class V>
void preconditoner(const std::string & filename, M &A, V &b) {

std::ifstream myfile;

myfile.open(filename.c_str());

int MM, NN, PP;

// ignore headers and comments  
while(myfile.peek()=='%') myfile.ignore(2048,'\n');

//information from MatrixMarket MM is number of rows 
//NN is number of columns, PP is terms
myfile>>MM>>NN>>PP;

double *PRE=new double[MM];

// get information from MatrixMarket
for(int i=0, j=0; i<PP; i++) {   
// mm is the row of element, nn is the column of element
// data is the value of element
 int mm,nn;
    double data;
    myfile>>mm>>nn>>data;
        if(mm==nn) {
        // inverse of P : Pii=( 1/Aii )
        PRE[j]=1./data;
        j++;
    }
}

// Jacobi preconditioner with Yale sparse matrix format : (inverse of P) *A
for(int i=0; i<A.m; i++) {
    for(int j=A.columnptr[i]; j<A.columnptr[i+1]; j++) {
        A.a[j]=A.a[j]*PRE[A.lineindex[j]];
    }
}

// right hand side : (inverse of P )*b
for(int i=0; i<A.m; i++) b.a[i]=b.a[i]*PRE[i];


}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Are you sure that preconditioner multiplication on A is correct? Also please provide some example of small SLAE on which you have tried you solvers.

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is right. I have tried on 4x4 and 5x5 matrices, it worked very well. but with 1806x1806 matrix, it got very strange values. @NikolayKondratyev